# 301 Unless Specific File Exists

Tags: .htaccess

I've been looking around but can't find an exact solution for this.

I have a site that I want to redirect UNLESS they type in any existing URL.

For example (these should worok with or without the www):

```
www.site.com -> redirect to sub.site.com
www.site.com/nonexistant.php -> does not so redirect to sub.site.com
www.site.com/index1.php -> exists so show it
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks, Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, this should do it;

```
# Turn rewrites on
RewriteEngine On

# First rewrite the site root to the new site.    
RewriteRule ^$ http://sub.site.com [L,R=301]

# ...else if the request doesn't match a directory...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# ...and it doesn't match a file...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# ...then redirect to http://sub.site.com/
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://sub.site.com [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a user-defined 404 page and put this in it:

```
<?php

header("Location: http://sub.site.com");

?>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the 404?  Kind of hard to explain here without a long drawn out explanation but if possible I'd like to do it in the .htaccess file

Comment: It seems to be possible with a .htaccess file: (quick googling) http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/custom404.shtml